# assertion fails in groovy even though the output are the same

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am unsure why the following is not working.

I am simply comparing a response with a range of values. The response comes from a json where front end the cost looks like:

```
20, 25, 40, 50
```

But when you grab it, it is displayed as `[[20.0000, 25.0000, 40.0000, 50.0000]]`

So I flattened the response like so:

```
json.groups.options.cost.flatten()
```

This outputs:

```
[20.0000, 25.0000, 40.0000, 50.0000]
```

Now I want to compare the above with some hardcoded values. So I created this variable:

```
def cost = [20, 25, 40, 50].collect { "${it}.0000" }
```

And this outputs:

```
[20.0000, 25.0000, 40.0000, 50.0000]
```

So when I assert them both together, I expect they work but they don't.

```
assert cost == json.groups.options.cost.flatten()
```

Now what is interesting is that if I perform the same assertion but cost is set as below:

```
def cost = [20.0000, 25.0000, 40.0000, 50.0000]
```

The assertion passes. How come it only works for this and how can I get it working the original way with the `.collect` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not assert because you are trying to compare `List<GString>` with `List<BigDecimal>`. In general you should not have to worry about decimal points in comparing such lists, because:

```
 assert [20, 25, 40, 50] == [20.0000, 25.0000, 40.0000, 50.0000]
```

where first list is `List<Integer>` and the second one is `List<BigDecimal>`.

You can check what type of list is `json.groups.options.cost.flatten()` and if this is not `List<BigDecimal>` you can convert it by

```
json.groups.options.cost.flatten().collect { new BigDecimal(it) }
```

and then compare simply with `[20, 25, 40, 50]`